# SDL2 undefined reference error, using premake5 for building, Arch Linux

Tags: c++, linker, premake, arch

I tried to build a c++ project that uses sdl2 with premake5 as my buildsystem. My goal was simply to get a window running, using the SDL2 code, provided by lazyfoo on SDL2:
https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php

For this, I downloaded the SDL2 source and tried to compile it as a static library as explained on the official premake website:
https://premake.github.io/docs/Linking

The source is from
https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.30.1
, specifically the SDL2-2.30.1.zip file.

I get an undefined reference error to SDL_INIT, SDL_GetError, SDL_CreateWindow and basically every other SDL function, I am using in my code.

After failing multiple times, I followed this tutorial on github to get a static library working in the first place.
https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Tutorial-Premake-example-with-GLFW-and-OpenGL

I removed all the opengl and glfw code, since I just wanted to get a simple print function working. After I succeeded, I just copied the code and updated it to fit the SDL2 include directories and file paths.

Now I get an undefined reference error as described above.

My premake5.lua looks like this:

```
workspace "Premake Test"
    location "Generated"
    language "C++"
    architecture "x86_64"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        symbols "On"
    
    filter "configurations:Release"
        optimize "On"

    filter { }

    targetdir("Build/Bin/%{prj.name}/%{cfg.longname}")
    objdir("Build/Obj/%{prj.name}/%{cfg.longname}")


project "SDL"
    kind "StaticLib"
    includedirs "libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include"
    files "libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/*"


function useSDL()
    includedirs "libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include"
    links "SDL"
end


project "TestLib"
    kind "StaticLib"
    files "libs/testlib/**"


function useExampleLib()
    includedirs "libs/testlib"
    links "TestLib"
end

project "App"
    kind "WindowedApp"
    files "src/**"

    useSDL()
    useExampleLib()
```

the ExampleLib Project is just my first try to get a general static library working

my main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;


int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

    print("Wenn das klappt, dann WTF!!!");

    SDL_Window *window = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *screenSurface = nullptr;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL could not be initialized!  Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL_Premake_Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL window could not be created!  Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    
    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
            if (e.type ==  SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;

    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0; 
}
```

my directory looks like this:

```
PREMAKE_TEST/
  libs/
    SDL2-2.30.1/
      include/          (contains all the .h files)
      src/              (contains all the .c files)
    testlib/
      test.cpp
      test.h
  src/
    main.cpp
  premake5.lua
```

to build my project, I first ran `premake5 gmake` and then `make` in the "Generate" folder, generated by premake.

The exact error I got after running make looks like this:

```
$ make
==== Building SDL (debug) ====
==== Building TestLib (debug) ====
==== Building App (debug) ====
Linking App
/usr/bin/ld: ../Build/Obj/App/Debug/main.o: in function `main':
/home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:18:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:20:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:24:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:27:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:31:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:32:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `SDL_MapRGB'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:32:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `SDL_FillRect'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:33:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:38:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:42:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../dev/premake_test/Generated/../src/main.cpp:43:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
make[1]: *** [App.make:81: ../Build/Bin/App/Debug/App] Fehler 1
make: *** [Makefile:43: App] Fehler 2
```

In case, this is important, my system is garuda-linux, arch based.
I also thought, the problem might be that the `#include SDL.h` includes the system SDL but I wasn't able to confirm this.
Also there might be ways to do this using cmake or g++ but I want to find a solution using premake since it seems to be a great and flexible way to build c++ projects in general.

I hope, this post is not a duplicate but every post, I have read so far has not helped me solve my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

**EDIT:**
the output I got after running `make -n`

```
$make -n
echo "==== Building SDL (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C . -f SDL.make config=debug
:
echo "==== Building TestLib (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C . -f TestLib.make config=debug
:
echo "==== Building App (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C . -f App.make config=debug
echo Linking App
g++ -o "../Build/Bin/App/Debug/App" ../Build/Obj/App/Debug/main.o    -L/usr/lib64 -m64 ../Build/Bin/SDL/Debug/libSDL.a ../Build/Bin/TestLib/Debug/libTestLib.a
```

result of `make -n` after `make clean`

```
make -n
echo "==== Building SDL (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C . -f SDL.make config=debug
echo Creating ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug
mkdir -p ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug
echo SDL.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL.c"
echo SDL_assert.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_assert.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_assert.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_assert.c"
echo SDL_dataqueue.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_dataqueue.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_dataqueue.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_dataqueue.c"
echo SDL_error.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_error.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_error.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_error.c"
echo SDL_guid.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_guid.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_guid.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_guid.c"
echo SDL_hints.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_hints.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_hints.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_hints.c"
echo SDL_list.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_list.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_list.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_list.c"
echo SDL_log.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_log.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_log.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_log.c"
echo SDL_utils.c
cc   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_utils.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_utils.d" -c "../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/SDL_utils.c"
echo Linking SDL
ar -rcs "../Build/Bin/SDL/Debug/libSDL.a" ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_assert.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_dataqueue.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_error.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_guid.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_hints.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_list.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_log.o ../Build/Obj/SDL/Debug/SDL_utils.o 
:
echo "==== Building TestLib (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C . -f TestLib.make config=debug
echo Creating ../Build/Obj/TestLib/Debug
mkdir -p ../Build/Obj/TestLib/Debug
echo test.cpp
g++   -MD -MP   -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/TestLib/Debug/test.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/TestLib/Debug/test.d" -c "../libs/testlib/test.cpp"
echo Linking TestLib
ar -rcs "../Build/Bin/TestLib/Debug/libTestLib.a" ../Build/Obj/TestLib/Debug/test.o 
:
echo "==== Building App (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C . -f App.make config=debug
echo Creating ../Build/Obj/App/Debug
mkdir -p ../Build/Obj/App/Debug
echo main.cpp
g++   -MD -MP  -I../libs/SDL2-2.30.1/include -I../libs/testlib -m64 -fPIC -g  -o "../Build/Obj/App/Debug/main.o" -MF "../Build/Obj/App/Debug/main.d" -c "../src/main.cpp"
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../Build/Bin/SDL/Debug/libSDL.a', needed by '../Build/Bin/App/Debug/App'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:43: App] Error 2
```

Comment: I don't know anything about premake but I'd guess that `files "libs/SDL2-2.30.1/src/*"` isn't recursive

Comment: It actually isn't which is on purpose because I get another error when writing src/** . I thought, it shouldn't make a difference since the SDL Project by itsself builds successfully and all the functions I am using right now are defined in SDL.c and other files which are placed directly in the src/ directory

Comment: Are the sdl files getting compiled as c or c++? If they're being treated as c++ the symbol names will be mangled and not match the header files. Have you checked the compiler commands that premake is using?

Comment: no, I haven't done this. I also don't know, how to check what compiler commands premake uses or how to check for that. Do you mean, what command is executed when using "make"? I have added the language "C" to my SDL project now which didn't change anything and I ran "make -n" which got me the output I added to my post. Is this what you meant? Btw, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: You probably need to do a make clean as it doesn't look like anything is being built so no commands are being printed. Is there a reason you're not just using a sdl library pre-built with their own build system?

Comment: I ran the ./autogen.sh script that comes with the library and ./configure afterwards. Then I build SDL using make by myself. Now I get an error that <dbus/dbus.h> is not found in SDL_dbus.h which is an improvement I guess?!. Altough now I don't know how to fix that since I have dbus installed but it is located in usr/include/dbus-1.0 which is probably not recognized because of its name. The only reason why im not using a prebuilt library is just because premake can theoretically do that (I think) and I want to learn about premake

Comment: I also recreated the same project and ran `make clean` and then `make -n`. The result of this is in my post now

Comment: " I first ran `premake5 gmake`" gmake generator is deprecated, prefer `premake5 gmake2` (even if it should not do any difference here).

Comment: It seems issue is your compilation of SDL (both my projects which use SDL use the one from system). `externalincludedirs "usr/include/dbus-1.0"` (or `sysincludirs` for older premake version) might help to build after autogen.sh script.